# How to prove this recursive sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,1)$ be any function (possibly not continous) whose ranges lies in $(0,1)$. For a recursive sequence $a_1=1, a_2=f(a_1), a_3=\frac{1}{a_2},a_4=f(a_3),...,a_n=1/a_{n-1} $ if n is odd or $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$ if n is even.

How do I prove that $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence? I have a strong feeling that I should argue that the sequence is bounded, and  use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to prove that a convergent subsequence exists. However, I don't see any bounds for the sequence...

Comment: HINT: The subsequence $\langle a_{2n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is bounded.

Comment: I see that. But $a_{2n-1}$ is not bounded... Is it? Then how do I argue that the sequence is bounded?

Comment: You don’t need the whole sequence to be bounded. You **do** need to remember that a subsequence of a subsequence of $\langle a_n:n\ge 1\rangle$ is itself just a subsequence of $\langle a_n:n\ge 1\rangle$.

Comment: Then should I create a subsequence $a_{2n}$ of $a_n$ and argue that the subsequence $a_{2n}$ is bounded by 0 and 1, thus there exists a convergent subsequence of $a_{2n}$, which is also a subsequence of $a_n$?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I had in mind.